# OpenCV Blob Detector has offset on found position

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I've simplified this down about as far as I can, and still get the error, so I'm thinking this is an OpenCV bug... but trying to confirm I'm not doing something dumb first.

I have this image:

[image: thresholded image]

Which SimpleBlobDetector is detecting as

[image: thresholded image with detection]:

As you can see, there are two small blobs that are detected properly, but the main large blob is offset from the actual position by about 20 pixels in the x direction and 10 pixels in the y direction.  What am I doing wrong?

Sample app that displays this error:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    cv::Mat im = imread("blob_error.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Set up SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
    cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params{};

    // Filter by color
    params.filterByColor = true;
    params.blobColor = 255;

    // Change grayscale search thresholds - since the input is a pre-binary-thresholded image, just use some values in the middle of the gray range
    // Note that simpleblobfinder does multiple passes at each threshold, exclusively, so the below is equivalent to a single pass at 128
    // The docs say the min is inclusive and the max is exclusive, but setting (128,129) yields zero detections
    params.minThreshold  = 127;
    params.maxThreshold  = 129;
    params.thresholdStep = 1;

    // Consider very-close blobs to be the same blob
    params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 5;

    // Filter by Area.  Always want to filter out tiny noise blobs
    params.filterByArea = true;
    params.minArea = 10;                                                              // Minimum size just to ignore noise
    params.maxArea = static_cast<float>(im.size().width * im.size().height) * 0.9f  ; // Let's say maximum size is 90% of the visible area.

    // Filter by Circularity (skipping)
    params.filterByCircularity = false;
    params.minCircularity = 0.1;
    params.maxCircularity = 1;

    // Filter by Convexity (skipping)
    params.filterByConvexity = false;
    params.minConvexity = 0;//.67;

    // Filter by Inertia (skipping)
    params.filterByInertia = false;
    params.minInertiaRatio = 0;//0.30;

    // Perform the detection
    cv::Ptr<cv::SimpleBlobDetector> detector = cv::SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector->detect( im, keypoints );

    cv::Mat im_with_keypoints;
    drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
    imshow("keypoints", im_with_keypoints);
    imwrite("blob_error_detected.png", im_with_keypoints);
    cvWaitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

I am using OpenCV 3.4.2

---

Edit -- here is the image without the center circle:

[image]

And here is the detection result (without circularity filtering)

[image]

Comment: I suggest  using  findcontour instead  to have more  control  over what you  want  to  achieve.

Comment: I'm actually using a collection of detection mechanisms, including contours -- but I'm concerned by this strange result and why it gives that offset.  I want to be sure I'm not missing something, and if not, plan to submit it to the opencv bug tracker.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug .please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The BlobDetector is actually detecting the centroid of the largest blob you have their not the circular one! So the Blobdetector result is right .

If your goal is to detect that circular blob in center then set :

```
// Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = true;
params.minCircularity = 0.5;
params.maxCircularity = 1;
```

Edit : detecting all blobs based on Area  (Blob detector)

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2\core\mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
cv::Mat im = imread("C:\\Users\\RaonOtics_Ziri\\Desktop\\vid\\test3.png", 
cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

// Set up SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;

params.filterByInertia = false;
params.filterByConvexity = false;
params.filterByCircularity = false;
params.filterByColor = true;

// Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 10;
params.maxThreshold = 255;
params.blobColor = 255;

// Filter by Area
params.filterByArea = true;
params.minArea = 0;
params.maxArea = 90000000;
params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 0.0f;

// Perform the detection
cv::Ptr<cv::SimpleBlobDetector> detector = 
cv::SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector->detect(im, keypoints);

cv::Mat im_with_keypoints;
drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 
cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT);

imshow("keypoints", im_with_keypoints);

imwrite("blob_error_detected.png", im_with_keypoints);
cvWaitKey(0);

return 0;
```

}

You'll get this result :

[image]

and with circularity filtering enabled  (min = 0.5 max = 1) you get :

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, although I don't think it's detecting that large blob as having a size that equal to the size of the smaller blob. To test, I removed the center circle and ran again with the 0.5-1.0 circularity range you suggested.  It only finds the two small circles.  If I disable the circularity filter I get a large detection, but there's no way I can make it return the smaller offset circle from my original result without that center circle present in the source image.  Please see my edit with the new images.

Comment: To test only the blob Size  you have to sett all other  parameters to false.  as you can see here (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/blobdetector.cpp )      the class constructor has default values for those parameters.

Comment: So, I do have those other parameters disabled in my original code, but to confirm, I tested with your code.  Using your code above, please try using the cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS style of keypoints to see what i'm talking about.  I just tested it with RICH_KEYPOINTS with my modified image (without the center blob) and I'm seeing the same result (for the main blob) that I noted in my edit above.  BTW, thank you for digging through this!

Answer (score 1):

Aaah... figured it out -- huge thank you to @ziri for bouncing this around.

For binary images, use these parameters:

```
params.minThreshold  = 128;
params.maxThreshold  = 129;
params.thresholdStep = 1;

params.minRepeatability = 1;
```

In my original comment I noted that setting the min/max to 128/129 did not work and assumed the documentation about the minThreshold being inclusive was wrong, but it is right.  The reason for the failure was instead that, by default, at least two passes of thresholding is required in order for blobs to be returned.

The core issue is that SimpleBlobDetector isn't intended for binary images.  As I noted in my question, I ended up not using it already and using contours directly, but wanted to understand the reason for the strange result.

As to that strange result, don't have enough time currently to confirm, but it looks like the SimpleBlobDetectorImpl::detect method here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/blobdetector.cpp merges the center position of blobs, but not the sizes.  I suspect that this makes a lot more sense on grayscale images than it does on binary images.

Core takeaway is, for binary images, use minRepeatability = 1 and set the thresholds to 128/129/1 as noted above.  (or else don't use SimpleBlobDetector and use contours directly).